# Label text not updating through a variable value

Tags: forms, label, ironpython

I am trying to update a value to a variable and to see the value in a label, but the label doesn't update unless I set it text value directly , not through a variable. how can I manage to control label with my var?

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")

from System.Windows.Forms import Form, Application, Label, Button
from System.Drawing import Point, Size

class IForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):

        # Main Form
        self.CenterToScreen()

        v = "one"

        # Label1
        self.label1 = Label()
        self.label1.Text = v
        self.label1.Location = Point(30, 30)
        self.Controls.Add(self.label1)

        # Label1
        self.label2 = Label()
        self.label2.Text = v
        self.label2.Location = Point(30, 60)
        self.Controls.Add(self.label2)

        #button
        self.button = Button()
        self.button.Text = "push"
        self.button.Click += self.push
        self.Controls.Add(self.button) 

    def push(self, sender, event):
        global v
        v = "three"
        self.label2.Text = "three"

Application.Run(IForm())
```

Comment: Have you thought about what is going on? How is the Label ialerted of the a change in the variable?

Comment: do you think if I knew I were asking? lol

Comment: perhaps I should refer to a function who will update all labels values? like
 self.label#.Text = "value" 
am I right? any other option?

Comment: Usually UI/frameworks allow you to bind different objects in a way that changes in one are reflected in the other. Just check the documentation of what you are using

Answer (score 0):

after some searches of key word bind I came up with this but still can't make it work :(

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")

from System.Windows.Forms import Form, Application, Label, Button, Binding
from System.Drawing import Size, Point, Font

class myform(Form):

    def __init__(self):

        # Main Form
        self.ClientSize = Size(250, 100)
        self.CenterToScreen()

        button = Button()
        button.Text = "Bind"
        button.Click += self.onset
        self.Controls.Add(button)  

        val = "1. initial val"
        font = Font("Arial", 14)

        # Label1
        self.label1 = Label()
        self.label1.Text = val
        self.label1.Font = font
        self.label1.Location = Point(30, 50)
        self.label1.Parent = self

        bind = Binding("Text", val, val)

    def onset(self, sender, event):
        global val
        val = "2. suscess !"

dialog = myform()
Application.Run(dialog)
```